# Learning Ruby: return value

Tags: ruby, return-value, implicit

I'm learning Ruby, but I'm having trouble with the whole implicit return value thing.  Someone please tell me why this returns an empty vector:

```
  3 def get_filenames(path)
  4   filenames = []
  5 
  6   if (path == ".") || (path == "..")
  7     []
  8   elsif File.directory? path
  9     Dir.entries(path).each do |sub_path|
 10       filenames += get_filenames(sub_path)
 11     end
 12   else #presumably it's a file
 13     [File.basename(path,".*")]
 14   end
 15 end
```

It should be returning an array of all file names (sans their extension) found when recursively searching from the argument path.

Assume that I call the function with "/tmp" and tmp contains 2 files: "A.txt" and "B.m" and then a directory which contains 1 file "C.exe".  I want this function to return ["A","B","C"]

Comment: What's `path` and what files are in that path?

Comment: Do you want to fetch all the file present in a folder(even if they are present in nested directories in current directory)??

Comment: @Cody - yep, that's what I want

Comment: Add a print statement on each and find out where it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, `Dir.entries` does not get absolute paths, so when you try calling `get_filenames(sub_path)` you call for a relative filename path (and your function receives an absolute path)

use this:

```
def get_files(dir)
   files = []
   Find.find(dir) { |path| files << File.basename(path,".*") if FileTest.file?(path) }
   return files
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution to your query...
Find every file present in the current directory and sub-directories

```
{Find.find("", "#{path}") do |file|
 if File.file?(file)
   filenames << file.to_s
 end
end
}
```

Comment: Plus 1 for a more concise answer, but I really want to learn *why* my code doesn't work rather than be given an script that does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement has three paths; the first returns an empty array, and the last returns a single element wrapped in an array. So far so good.

But the middle path returns the value of `Dir.entries`, which itself returns all the entries for the folder identified by `path`. The `each` iterator produces the side effect of recursively calling `get_filenames` and appending them to the local variable `filenames`, but the return value of `Dir.entries` is not affected by this -- it still returns all the entries in the folder.

To get the result you want, just add `filenames` after the Dir.entries call.

Answer (score 0):

It is finding your `if` statement to be true, I believe, causing it to exit on the first pass through.  What happens if you remove that portion of the logic (move `elseif` to `if` so you just have `if` and `else`?

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine as expected.

Try adding print statements in the argument and each one of the returned values to see what is actually happening in your case.

It is possible that your think you're passing one value when in fact you're passing another.